# Repo with non android projects

Tags: android, git, repo

I am working on a project where I am trying to unite several modules into one solution. The modules are each in their own folder and are git repositories. These are all stored in `C:\sourcecode\Modules` Eventually they will be on GitHub. After deep reviews of different methods of using a Solutions made up of Module stored in git repositories, I decided to try Google's `Repo` that was built for AOSP.

I installed all the tools based on the Repo requirements here https://source.android.com/setup/develop and created a folder `C:\sourcecode\Repotest` in that folder I created a file called default.xml. The contents of that folder are very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>

  <remote  name="origin"
           fetch="/c/sourcecode/Modules" />
  <default revision="master"/>

  <project path="AnalystQualification" name="AnalystQualification" />
</manifest>
```

I launch git-bash as administrator and run:

```
$ cd /c/sourcecode/Repotest/
$ repo init -u default.xml
```

I get the output:

```
$ repo init -u default.xml
Downloading manifest from default.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\sourcecode\Repotest\.repo\repo\main.py", line 630, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\sourcecode\Repotest\.repo\repo\main.py", line 604, in _Main
    result = run()
  File "C:\sourcecode\Repotest\.repo\repo\main.py", line 597, in <lambda>
    run = lambda: repo._Run(name, gopts, argv) or 0
  File "C:\sourcecode\Repotest\.repo\repo\main.py", line 266, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "C:\sourcecode\Repotest\.repo\repo\subcmds\init.py", line 531, in Execute
    self._SyncManifest(opt)
  File "C:\sourcecode\Repotest\.repo\repo\subcmds\init.py", line 232, in _SyncManifest
    default_branch = m.ResolveRemoteHead()
  File "C:\sourcecode\Repotest\.repo\repo\project.py", line 1926, in ResolveRemoteHead
    output = self.bare_git.ls_remote('-q', '--symref', '--exit-code', name, 'HEAD')
  File "C:\sourcecode\Repotest\.repo\repo\project.py", line 3040, in runner
    raise GitError('%s %s: %s' %
error.GitError: manifests ls-remote: fatal: invalid gitfile format: default.xml
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Downloading Repo source from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
```

I think this error is telling me that setup in default.xml cant see the .git folder in the `modules/analystqualification` directory but I can see it if I `ls -l`

```
$ ls -l /C/sourcecode/Modules/AnalystQualification
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 1 adam.wheeler 1049089 0 Jan 12 10:01 Setup_AQ/
```

Any help is appreciated here. Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
repo init -u url_to_manifest_repo -m foo.xml -b manifest_repo_branch
```

`url_to_manifest_repo` should be a git repository that tracks `foo.xml`. It can be either in the local disk or in a remote hosting server. In your case, it's `/c/sourcecode/Repotest`. Make sure that `/c/sourcecode/Repotest` is a git repository and `default.xml` has been trakced.

`foo.xml` is the manifest file's path relative to `url_to_manifest_repo` root. `-m foo.xml` can be omitted. If so, `-m default.xml` is used by default.

`manifest_repo_branch` is the branch that holds the specific version of `foo.xml`. If `-b manifest_repo_branch` is omitted, it defaults to `-b master`.

So in your case the command would be:

```
repo init -u /c/sourcecode/Repotest -m default.xml -b master
```

or simply:

```
repo init -u /c/sourcecode/Repotest
```

For a local repository, it could also be `-u file:///c/sourcecode/Repotest`.

Comment: Thank you! this solved it with the exception of one thing. I did get it fixed but I dont understand why it fixed it. I was still getting an error that said something along the lines of no repository found in defaul.xml. it was fixed by adjusting the default tag to: `<default revision="master" remote="origin"/>` Do you know why this worked?

Comment: @AdamWheeler the default remote `origin` is declared in `<default/>`. You can specify `remote="foo"` in every `<project/>`. If it's missing, it falls back to the one in `<default/>`. If it's not there either, it raises an error. The remote name is used as the cloned project's default remote, which is `origin` by convention. If it's `remote="foo"`, then it's also `foo` in the cloned project. And then you'll need to use `git push foo master` or `git pull foo master`.

Comment: `revision="master` also works this way. It's a fallback if `revision="foo"` is missing in `<project/>`. For more details, you could check `.repo/repo/docs/manifest-format.txt`.